# Server returns undefined JSON data submitted using form

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-review-app-with-ionic-2-mongodb-node/) but since I'm using a newer version of angular and ionic, I faced some problems.

Here's a portion of my code

```
createReview(review){    
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/reviews', JSON.stringify(review), {headers: headers})
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log("creating new review.." + res);
      });
}
```

Function createReview() is supposed to send a JSON POST with all the review data to my nodejs server, but apparently the server receives undefined instead.

```
POST /api/reviews 200 222.839 ms - 309
creating review
title: undefined
description: undefined
rating: undefined
```

Using POSTMAN, in the Headers I set 'Content-Type: application/json' and Body to raw JSON(application/json) and sent this data

```
{
    "title":"postman tt",
    "description":"postman desc",
    "rating":"30"
}
```

and the server can receive the data without any problem. What should I change in my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow turned out I just need to remove

`JSON.stringify()` and leave it to just review like below

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/reviews', review, {headers: headers})
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log("creating new review.." + res);
      });
```

p/s: Not sure if it's appropriate for me to answer this myself here, but I think it could help other angular/ionic noob like me who stumbled with the same problem.

Comment: It *is* appropriate and exactly for the reason you gave.